# Allocating more space to ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Can we allocate more space to ubuntu without reinstalling it in a dual boot system? I also want my ubuntu data to be preserved.

Comment: You can use [GParted](https://gparted.org/) to resize partitions. You will have to make space (just like you did when you were dual booting) and then try resizing from the Ubuntu OS.
Check out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/957448/how-to-resize-my-dual-boot-partitions

Comment: From my personal experience: Whatever happens, DO NOT resize Linux partitions through the disk manager (Win + X + M). Use it only to create unallocated space. You can use GParted to manage partitions on Ubuntu

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, you can but should you? *I also want my ubuntu data to be preserved* <- This suggests you don't have backups. You're strongly advised to do your backups before trying to do what you want. ANY partition change carries the risk of data loss and in your case you may have to *move* one partition before being able to expand it and that carries an even higher risk.